# Can't extend bezier curve without creating infinite loop curves

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm trying to make some basic ribbon Bezier curve elements and I can't seem to extend without making infinite loops.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure what you mean, but you can click here on "cyclic" so your ribbon will have ends.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I clicked it and it created a loop and then I unclicked it and my issue was gone. Thank you